# Thread-safe normal random number generator in F#

Tags: .net, random, f#

Needing a random number generator that returns a sample from a normal (Gaussian) distribution,  I've ported to F# a portion of [John D. Cook's C# generator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25172/Simple-Random-Number-Generation):

```
let mutable m_w = 521288629u
let mutable m_z = 362436069u

let private getUint () =
    m_z <- 36969u * (m_z &&& 65535u) + (m_z >>> 16)
    m_w <- 18000u * (m_w &&& 65535u) + (m_w >>> 16)
    (m_z <<< 16) + m_w

let private setSeed () =
    let dt = System.DateTime.Now
    let x = dt.ToFileTime ()
    m_w <- uint32 (x >>> 16)
    m_z <- uint32 (x % 4294967296L)

let private getUniform () =
    let u = getUint ()
    (float u + 1.) * 2.328306435454494e-10

let private randomNormal () =
    let u1 = getUniform ()
    let u2 = getUniform ()
    let r = sqrt (-2. * (log u1))
    let theta = 2. * System.Math.PI * u2
    r * sin (theta)

/// Returns a normal (Gaussian) random sample with mean 0 and standard deviation 1
let randn () =
    setSeed ()
    randomNormal ()

/// Returns an array of normal (Gaussian) random samples
let randns n m =
    setSeed ()
    [| for i in 0 .. n - 1 -> randomNormal () |]
```

This implementation works fine but is not thread safe. Given that the code that depends on it makes extensive use of the Thread Parallel Library, I need to make it thread safe.

This does not look obvious to me because at the core of the method lie two mutable members which are pretty much indispensable. Is there any other way to achieve thread-safety without resorting to locks?

Is there any other way to implement a normal pseudo-random generator using only immutable members?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using mutable members, you'd have no choice but use a lock.

However, you'd be better off with an immutable [record](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) containing `m_w` and `m_z` that you pass to your random functions.  They could return a tuple of your random value and a new record containing the updated random members.  Better yet, you could create a [computation expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) to handle generating randoms so you won't have to worry about passing the random record around.

Also, calling `setSeed` from within your random functions is bad.  Multiple subsequent calls will return the same vale.  You only want to set your seed once.

Comment: Good call on not calling setSeed every time, stupid oversight

Comment: I like this idea. Could you please elaborate on the computation expression option (I'm not familiar with the concept)?

Comment: It would look something like:
    `rnd {
     let! a = GetNext 10;
     let! b = GetExponential 2.5;
     let! c = GetNormal;
     return a, b, c
    }`

Comment: Basically, you define a context in which your random number generator is implicitly used (in the `let!` statements).  The `rnd {...}` expression would be typed something like `YourRandomGenType -> 'a`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a trivial thread-safe solution using System.Random, if it's any help:

```
let random =
  let rand = System.Random()
  let locker = obj()
  fun () -> lock locker rand.Next
```

Comment: You can actually use this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform .  To convert from random numbers generated by `System.Random` to normally distributed numbers.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to put all `m_w`/`m_z` and related functions into a class. Like this:

```
type Random = 
    let setSeed() = ...
    let randomNormal() = ...
```

After that there are at least two solutions: launch every thread with its own instance of the `Random` object; or use `ThreadLocal<Random>` class for the same thing -- guaranty that every thread has own instance of the `Random` class.

EDIT:
Also, `MailboxProcessor` with `PostAndReply` method is a good way to share single generator between threads. No need to worry about synchronization.

Comment: The problem with creating a new instance every time is that they risk getting the same seed. I think this is quite likely to happen in a Array.Parallel.map (fun n -> let r = new Random () ...) scenario.

Comment: @FrancescoDeVittori: You could incorporate thread-specific data in your seed value, like `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`.

Comment: @FrancescoDeVittori Yes, using `DateTime` for initial seed is a bad idea. But you can use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes` or something similar for it.

Comment: @Daniel You're assuming they aren't created on the same thread, which is probably quite likely.

Comment: @JonHarrop: Yes, if each thread has its own `Random` object, that's one way of initializing them with unique seed values.